# How do I send multiple id to controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to send my id to the controller, but my id was split by commas like `212,233,121`, which is from JavaScript. How do I send my id based on my value from my JavaScript based number comma split?

The url should like this `http://localhost/fics/public/reporting/reporting/getcust/212/233/121`, which is the number at the back, based on my value that split by commas.

Here is my code:

```js
for (var h = 0; h < storeItem.length; h++)
{
    if (l == storeItem[h]) {
        popVal = popVal + tempItem[i][l];
        //popval value from my other window .Example " 002,212,212"
    }
}
```

My view route button onclick:

```js
onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('reporting.getcust') }}')"
```

My web.php:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'reporting'], function () {
    Route::get('reporting/getcust/{id}','GenReportController@getcust')->name('reporting.getcust');
});
```

Controller:

```php
public function getcust(Request $request){  
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: send it in the url `?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3` like so, then you get an array

Answer (score 0):

If the JavaScript generates a URL like http://localhost/fics/public/reporting/reporting/getcust/002,212,212.
Then you can get all ids in your controller by using the `explode` method

```
public function getcust(Request $request)
{ 
    $ids = explode(",", $request->id);

    foreach ($ids as $id) 
    {
        echo $id;
    }
}
```